# Extracting text in of between specific <span> </span>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing my first (not print("hello world") python program but found a problem extracting what I really need from output. I checked many similar topics but it didn't work as expected.

```
page = requests.get(
"https://www.oferty.net/statystyki/012022/mieszkania-sprzedaz-"+cityChoose)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find('div', {"class": "subtitle2"})

print(content)
```

And I get:

```
<div class="subtitle2">
<span>
<span>Warszawa</span> - średnia cena 1m² w styczniu 2022 = 13 405 PLN </span>
</div>
```

How can I choose particular text to make it look like that?

> Warszawa - średnia cena 1m² w styczniu 2022 = 13 405 PLN

Answer (score 1):

Then you can find first `span` and get all text inside, as follows:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.oferty.net/statystyki/012022/mieszkania-sprzedaz-"+cityChoose)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find('div', {"class": "subtitle2"})

result = content.find('span').text
print(result)
# Warszawa - średnia cena 1m² w styczniu 2022 = 13 405 PLN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bso
sample_content = """<html>
<head>MyApp</head>
<body>
<div class="subtitle2">
<span>
<span>Warszawa</span> - średnia cena 1m² w styczniu 2022 = 13 405 PLN </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>"""
soup = bso(sample_content, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find('div', {"class": "subtitle2"})
print(''.join([t.text for t in content.findChildren()]))
```

Simple example [here](https://replit.com/@YusifAghayev/RewardingCriminalTransformation#main.py)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys! I tried your solution but for some reason didn't work. Maybe I did something wrong but found the way by just adding .text to print command as below:

```
page = requests.get(
"https://www.oferty.net/statystyki/012022/mieszkania-sprzedaz-"+cityChoose)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find('div', {"class": "subtitle2"})
print(content.text)
```

Comment: Oh, my solution had a typo. I just fixed. Anyway, your way also work although mine went one more step to `span` and get `.text`. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches - One is to call `.text` directly on the result finding the `<div>`, if there are no other tags holding text you do not like to scrape:

```
content = soup.find('div', {'class': 'subtitle2'}).text

print(content)
#Warszawa - średnia cena 1m² w styczniu 2022 = 13 405 PLN
```

Another is to select more specific for the `<span>`:

```
content = soup.find('div', {'class': 'subtitle2'}).find('span').text

print(content)
#Warszawa - średnia cena 1m² w styczniu 2022 = 13 405 PLN
```

Or go with `CSS SELECTORS`:

```
content = soup.select_one('div.subtitle2 span').text

print(content)
#Warszawa - średnia cena 1m² w styczniu 2022 = 13 405 PLN
```